# how run a loop without stopping the rest of the script in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, stdout, minecraft

im trying to make a discord bot that acts like a minecraft server console, however, and i feel like this is a very basic problem I want the bot to keep sending the output of a Minecraft server and also write inputs via messages in a specific channel, but of course, if you have a loop running the rest of the program doesn't run, I've tried multiprocess and multithreading but it didn't work because of the asynchronous functions.
this is me code:

```
minecraft_dir = r"C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\1.18 server - Copy"
executable = r'java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\1.18 server - Copy\server.jar" java'
process = None

async def start_serv(msg):
  os.chdir(minecraft_dir)
  process = subprocess.Popen(executable,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, text=True)
  for line in process.stdout:
    await msg.channel.send(line)

def serv_cmd(cmd):
  if cmd == "stop":
    process = None
  cmd = cmd + "\n"
  cmd = cmd.encode()
  process.stdin.write(cmd)
  process.stding.flush()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global process
  if message.author.id != client.user.id and message.channel.name == "mc-server-console":
    command = message.content
    command=command.lower()
    if command == "start":
      if process == None:
        await message.channel.send("yessir")
    if process != None:
      serv_cmd(command)
```

here is my multithreading attempt:

```
async def start_serv():
  os.chdir(minecraft_dir)
  process = subprocess.Popen(executable,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, text=True)
  for line in process.stdout:
    await channel.send(line)
    time.sleep(0.1)

def serv_cmd(cmd):
  if cmd == "stop":
    process = None
  cmd = cmd + "\n"
  cmd = cmd.encode()
  process.stdin.write(cmd)
  process.stding.flush()

def main():
  @client.event
  async def on_message(message):
    global process
    if message.author.id != client.user.id and message.channel.name == "mc-server-console":
      command = message.content
      command=command.lower()
      if command == "start":
        if process == None:
          await message.channel.send("yessir")
          thread2.start()
      if process != None:
        serv_cmd(command)

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=main)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=start_serv)
```

if anyone knows a way to only send messages when the output of the server updates, I think that would work too.

Comment: Can you show your attempts with multiprocessing and multi threading?

Comment: @jakub here u go I couldn't find my multiprocessing attempt but i don't think it was very different.

Comment: To do this you could just have your bot update every time it runs through the script. You could also create a cog to do this which should not stop any other script.

Comment: @EpicEfeathers how would I update the script?

Comment: Honestly I would just create a cog and have your loop in there, as it will not affect your other files.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Threading actually isn't a good move here. Most of the time Threads with `discord.py` aren't going to be "thread safe." You could mess around with Lock's but it's easier to avoid them as much as possible. Please note this is a prototype as I have not tested any of this (I don't have MC). I would take it as a concept and use it to guide you

Let's walk through a way to do what you want while not blocking the event loop.

```py
import os
import subprocess
import aiohttp
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Generic, TypeVar, Any

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from asyncio import AbstractEventLoop
    
B = TypeVar('B', bound='commands.Bot')

# We'll make a class caleld MinecraftRunner
# to hold all minecraft based operations
    
class MinecraftRunner(Generic[B]):
    def __init__(self, bot: B) -> None:
        self.bot: commands.Bot = bot
        self.loop: AbstractEventLoop = bot.loop
        self.session: aiohttp.ClientSession = getattr(bot, 'session', aiohttp.ClientSession())
        
        self.minecraft_dir: str = r"C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\1.18 server - Copy"
        self.executable: str = r'java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar "C:\Users\Pablo\Desktop\1.18 server - Copy\server.jar" java'
        
        # We'll use webhooks to send to the channel instead of `channel.send`. 
        # This will not rate-limit our bot.
        self.webhook_url: str = '' 
        
        # Using loop.create_task will allow us to not block
        # the main event loop.
        self.runner_task = self.loop.create_task(self.main_loop())
        
    async def send_to_webhook(self, *args, **kwargs) -> discord.WebhookMessage:
        if not (webhook := getattr(self, 'webhook', None)):
            self.webhook = webhook = await (discord.Webhook.from_url(self.webhook_url, session=self.session, bot_token=self.bot.http.token)).fetch()

        return await webhook.send(*args, **kwargs)
    
    async def main_loop(self) -> None:
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready() # Don't do anything until our bot is ready to do work.
        
        os.chdir(self.minecraft_dir)
        self.process = process = subprocess.Popen(self.executable,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
        
        for line in process.stdout:
            await self.send_to_webhook(line)
    
# Let's put our on_message into a simple cog as well
class MinecraftListener(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot: commands.Bot = bot
        self.minecraft_runner = MinecraftRunner(bot)
        
    def cog_unload(self) -> None:
        self.minecraft_runner.runner_task.cancel()
        
        try:
            delattr(self.minecraft_runner, 'runner_task')
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        
    async def send_command(self, command: str) -> None:
        command += '\n'
        command.encode()
        self.minecraft_runner.process.stdin.write(command)
        self.minecraft_runner.process.stdin.flush()
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message) -> Any:
        if message.author.bot: # This message was sent from a bot.
            return
        if message.webhook_id: # This message is a webhook message.
            return
        
        command = message.content.lower()
        channel = message.channel
        
        if command == 'start':
            if not hasattr(self.minecraft_runner, 'runner_task'):
                self.minecraft_runner.runner_task = self.minecraft_runner.loop.create_task(self.minecraft_runner.main_loop())
                return await channel.send('The process has been started.')
            
            return await channel.send('The process is already started.')
                
        elif command == 'stop': # Stop the process
            if not hasattr(self.minecraft_runner, 'runner_task'):
                return await channel.send('The process is not running!')
            
            return self.cog_unload()
        
        # This isn't a custom command, send it to the minecraft process
        await self.send_command(command)
```

Comment: thanks for answering my question, and sorry for taking so long I was away from my computer for a while. as you might have been able to tell from my terrible code, I am quite new to programming and I had to spend an hour reading documentation on this code to understand half of what's going on and to be honest I still don't understand how this would work and why you created a class and cog. I want to learn why you did all this rather than just copy so i would love if you could explain it to me

Comment: Add me on discord if you feel inclined, I can help you understand it Chai#9762

Comment: sounds good, I'm mushroom

Comment: don't want to sound needy but can u accept me on discord?